# Get id from html table when clicking an input inside the table

Tags: javascript, html-table

How can you get the id of a table when you click an input element?
I don't need the rowId etc.
I've tried parentNode.id but I can't seem to get the id.
In the end I'd like to do something like this:

```js
var tabelid = INPUT....parentNode.parentNode.id;
var table = document.getElementById(tabelid);
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: If the DOM is created correctly, then the parent of the TR is a TBODY.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, html5 allows for valid tables constructed without TBODY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f696a/)

#### Html

```
<table id="tblTest">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtTest" onclick="getParent.call(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using `call` here so that i get the elements context inside the `getParent` event callback.

#### Javascript

```
function getParent()
{
  var parent = this.parentNode;
  var tagName = "table";

  while (parent) { //Loop through until you find the desired parent tag name
  if (parent.tagName && parent .tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      alert(parent .id);
      return;
    }
      else
      {
          parent = parent .parentNode;
      }
 
  }
    
}
```

If you are using Jquery:-

in the click event you can just do `$(this).closest('table').attr('id')`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can use `closest` to find the closest matching ancestor like so:

```
var tableID = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function(e){
        tableID = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    });
]);
```

**Edit:**

If you actually want to do something with that table (for instance add a class), you could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function(e){
        tableID = $(this).closest('table').addClass('myClass');
    });
]);
```

This simply removes the need to fetch the table ID, store it, and then fetch the table based on it's ID.  Since you already found the table in order to get its ID you can just manipulate it right away.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ascend the DOM from TD to TABLE keeping in mind that browsers may inject a TBODY if you haven't specified it.  So, your code should look something like this:

```
var tableCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    cellCount = tableCells.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < cellCount; i += 1) {
    tableCells[i].onclick = function () {
        var tableId = getTableId(this);
        console.log(tableId);
    };
}

function getTableId(node) {
    var element = node;
    while (element.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'table') {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return element.id;
}
```

[Check out the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwWEm/1/).